# Achieve full-featured shift stream syntax

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Within my class, I overloaded the operator<< in order to achieve

```
MyObject << something1 << something2;

friend const std::string& operator<<(Logger& os, const std::string& msg);
```

But I just can do:

MyObject << something1;

If I add the second stream input (something2), I get a compiler error telling me there is not an operator for such as input.

So that, my question is: How can I achieve the intended syntax?

Answer (score 2):

`<<` must return the stream (as a reference). In other words, it should return its *first* (left-hand) argument.

`os << v1 << v2` is parsed as `(os << v1) << v2`, so for the outer call to use the same overloaded operator, the result of `os << v1` better be the same as the type of `os`.

Comment: So I'm forced to handle os? If I return MyObject as a reference I got the same problem.

Comment: Is `MyObject` a `Logger` or something else? And what do you mean by "handle" `os`. All you have to do is return it as-is.

Comment: Thanks rici, I did it by defining:
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& log, const std::string& msg);
So now, I can write:
MyObject << "msg 1" << msg 2";
All of that without having an ostream in my argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem. I need to return MyObject as a reference:

```
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& os, const std::string& msg);
```